# How to solve this type of multivariable integral (3 variables)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to calculate 
$ \int_B f(x)dx $
 for:
$f(x,y,z)=x*y*z$

The region is defined as:
$ R= \{0\le x \le 1,  y\ge0,  z\ge0,  0\le y+z\le1 \}$

The process of calculating multivariable integrals by itself is not that much complicated, but I do not know how to start or how to "write down" the integral.

Here is my attempt:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-z} \int_0^{1-y} (x*y*z) dz dy dx$

but I am not sure about it, as solving this won't give me a "number" in the end, but an expression with 
z
 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but the integratin domain is not quite correct, in the end no variables should be left as you correctly determined, and that is because of the superfluous $z$ in the bounds of $y$, the correct way would be following:

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} f(x,y,z)dz dy dx$$

Now we have $z \in [0,1-y]$ and $y \in [0,1]$, so certianly $0\leq y+z$ but because $z\leq 1-y$ we get $y+z \leq y + 1-z =1$.